# Different colored submit button on hover - HTML

Tags: html, css

I've created two submit buttons:

```
http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg
http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg
```

I want the first to show as my standard submit button (dark) and the second (light) to show on hover.

My code is as follows:

```
 <input name="submit" id="submit" type="image" src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg" width="314" height="40" value="Sign up" /></div>
```

CSS is:

```
submit:hover { background-image: url ('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg');
```

However the on hover image isn't showing, any idea why?

Comment: I think it's because your CSS selector is invalid, try using `#submit:hover { ... }`

Comment: If you are considering having more than one submit button with that style in your application you might like to explore the idea of using classes instead of ID's especially for css. But again it depends on your needs

Comment: Thanks for the tip Klye, I only intend to use this once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to drop the src attribute of your input, and use background-image instead in similar manner, as you tried to do on hover. Your attempt failed for two reasons - one you missed hash before referencing your element by it's id (or name), and then even if you make this step right you wouldn't see background image anyway because of src attribute of your input.
You can do it in this simple way:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/r7xb1xdf/1/)

```
    <input type="submit" id="submit" width="314" height="40" value="" />
```

and:

```
    #submit { 
       border:0;
       width:314px;
       height:40px;
       background-image: url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg'); 
    }
    #submit:hover { background-image: url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg');}
    #submit:focus, #submit:active {
       outline:none;
    }
```

EDIT:
You also have a closing div at the end of input tag - it's probably leftover from your whole code, but it makes HTML invalid without opening div.

Comment: Legend, thanks for the explanation and fiddle.

Is it possible to remove the word "submit" from showing?

Comment: yup - see my updated answer. I've also removed default outline from input on focus

Comment: If you want to take it further you can move setting up dimensions to your css, which will make your html, even cleaner.So `<input type="submit" id="submit" value="" />`

Comment: You should leave the value attribute in for Accessibility particularly because you are using images and not straight css. You would need to use the text-indent and text-transform to hide the text that gets added.

Comment: That is valid point @Sephorra. If you asked me I would opt out for using css only solution here, but this is probably out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks but again the button doesn't appear to be clickable (in Fiddle)

Comment: @user2696953 - it still "clickable" in the same manner as it was when you provided your fiddle. Do you mean, that the cursor is not changing to the pointer on hover? If so, then you just need to add `cursor:pointer` to your hover state, like so - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/r7xb1xdf/3/)

Comment: Thanks Robjez!! That worked a treat! Where can I learn more about CSS!?

Comment: well - you're just sitting in front of gazillions of learning resources - sites like: `http://css-tricks.com/`, `http://www.smashingmagazine.com/`, `http://alistapart.com/` will help you out. Start with some books like Handcrafted CSS or Bulletproof Web Design by Dan Cederholm. A list Apart has a good library of books - all these little books are worth reading, so got through them - all of them. But foremost you want to see how things are built, so signup to CodePen, pickup pens you like the most and study, how they are built. F12 in Chrome is your best friend here.

Comment: ....Avoid using frameworks (at least for now) and build your own stuff. Then occasionally go to the W3C site and read a one of the specs, you're interested in. There are also numbers of podcasts - google frontend development podcasts, if you want to listen about web stuff while going to work... Overall - "Just Build Websites".

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS selector is invalid for the submit button, you need to reference either the button in your CSS as:

This will style all submit buttons.

```
  input[type=submit] { }
```

This will style only the element (this case a submit button) with the ID of 'submit'

```
  #submit { }
```

So for example:

```
   input[type=submit]:hover { background-image: url ('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg');
```

If you want to style all submit buttons with the same background to begin with and same hover effect you should use:

```
    input[type=submit]:hover {  background-image: url ('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg'); }

    input[type=submit] { background-image: url: url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.,

```
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="image" width="314" height="40" value="Sign up" />

input#submit{
  background: url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg');
}
input#submit:hover { 
background: url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg');
}
```

Comment: I tried above i got a result then why down voted here?

Comment: @user2696953 use typed unwanted space for css and you called invalid css

Answer (score 0):

Why not change it to use CSS instead, that way you can re use the styling and update the text within the button without creating a new image.

HTML:

```
<button type="submit">Start Trial &#9658;</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    background: #4e6ea1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
         -o-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
}

button:hover {
    background: #84a3d9;
}
```

Comment: Hey Arty, this looks nice and is probably the way to go, however if I copy your code the submit button won't submit!

Comment: Do you know what is triggering your submit? It may be the id="submit"

Comment: No worries, glad it works. Hopefully this should give you a good base for your styling. If you want to take it one step further take a look a CSS3 transitions http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/ to ease the background colour change

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the base image as a src you cannot change it with css, you need javascript to do that. In order to achieve with css you need to do something like this.

```
 <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Sign up" />

.submit {
  background:url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg);
  text-indent: -9999px; 
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height:40px;
  width: 314px;
  border:0;
 }

.submit:hover{
   background:url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg);
 }
```

Note: the text transform is for ie7

Comment: I added both to my internal style sheet but had no luck - see: http://jsfiddle.net/f7oyhdut/

Comment: You missed the bracket for the first submit block of css, sorry It fell out of the code block, i've updated. Note: you should consider putting the images in a sprite sheet and using background position so you avoid the flicker on first load. Or better yet, use just css no images at all. Also you dont need the style tags on jsfiddle in the css just paste the css in.

Comment: Thanks, this again looks good but the buttons lost it's submit ability!?

Comment: Submits fine on your jsfiddle, have you got an updated version with any changes you have made?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="image" src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg" onMouseOver="this.src='http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg'" width="314" height="40" value="Sign up" />
```

use onMouseOver property

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the initial image of the button as css-background property aswell insted of defining it as html src attribute.

New HTML (i also added a submit class, dont use IDs for button syling):

```html
<input name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" type="image" width="314" height="40" value="Sign up" /></div>
```

New CSS (also added the class indicator .):

```css
.submit { 
  background-image: url ('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg');
}

.submit:hover { 
  background-image: url ('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you firstly have to give the button a background-image and then assign a new one when the user hovers it, otherwise it will be hidden behind.

```
 <input name="submit" id="submit" type="image" width="314" height="40" value="Sign up" />

input { 
    background-image: url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-dark.jpg');
}

input:hover { 
    background-image: url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light.jpg');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdxfye9e/

Comment: This would change all input items to that background, not the submit button. -1